# Display a number of divs one at a time (like a deck of cards)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a survey form. It is supposed to display one question at a time.

Every question has a number of radio buttons. When one radio button is clicked the question will be removed (display: none; maybe with a sliding animation) and the next one will come into view.

Here's a simplified version of the form and the structure we have so far. I haven't done that much front end programming before - so I don't  know if there's a simple standard way of doing this doing this with Javascript or jQuery?

Would very much appreciate some pointers in the right direction.
Here's the concept:

1. Display div with question #1
2. Click radiobutton
3. Hide div with question #1
4. Display div with question #2
5. Click a radiobutton
6. Hide div with question #2
   etc...

   ```
   <form method="post">

       <div id="question_1">
           <div class="question">
           Question 1
           </div>
           <div class="table">
               <input type="radio" value="1" name="rb_1">
               <input type="radio" value="2" name="rb_1">
           </div>
       </div>   

       <div id="question_2">
           <div class="question">
           Question 2
           </div>
           <div class="table">
               <input type="radio" value="1" name="rb_2">
               <input type="radio" value="2" name="rb_2">
           </div>
       </div> 

       <div id="question_3">
           <div class="question">
           Question 3
           </div>
           <div class="table">
               <input type="radio" value="1" name="rb_3">
               <input type="radio" value="2" name="rb_3">
           </div>
       </div> 

       <div id="question_4">
           <input type="submit" name="submit">
       </div> 

   </form>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This won't be extremely user friendly as is but does what you asked and gives an idea on approach

Made adjustment to move `class="question"` to the outer levels where the ID's are. Setting common classes on behavioral elements is typically simpler than targeting ID's

```
<div id="question_1" class="question">
```

JS

```
$(function(){    
    $('.question :radio').change(function(){
        $(this).closest('.question').hide().next().show();
    });    
});
```

There are lots of `form wizard` or `form steps` type plugins that you could use for this that offer more animation, prev/next buttons and visual step indicators etc

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uxqeL6qq/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Make the default for all divs hidden. When a radio button in a div is clicked, display the next div and hide that one. So in jQuery, use get elements on the divs, and set their display property to none. Store each div into an array of divs. Have a function that activates on click of a radio button. When it is clicked, go to the next div in the array from the radio button div and set its display to block.